# Is it possible to upload Change sets from Production to Sandbox?

Tags: sandbox, change-set, production

I was trying to upload a change set from my production org o sandbox but I always got the same error:

```
Change set: CP_ChangeSet10/01/2014 (04td0000000VI0v)
Organization: Casas Platino (Production) (00Dd0000000hG6b)
User: Ivan Rivera Macias (005d0000001hG8r)
Error Number: 1499735274-20466 (-279048592)

Please try to upload your change set again. If it does not succeed, contact Customer Support and provide the error number listed above.
```

So I thought that I was trying to do something that's not possible.

Comment: You definitely can. Where are you getting this error?

Comment: I received this error after selecting the Target Organization and tried to upload the change set.

Comment: There might just be an issue with the sandbox's instance  right now, maybe tomorrow it will work itself out.

Comment: I tried to upload it again and  could do it, it's a little strange.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can deploy change sets between any two orgs tied to the production instance, including from a Production instance to a Sandbox. If you go to outbound change sets in your Production environment, you will see the option.

You might just be experiencing a temporary issue with your Salesforce sandbox instance.